# Instance variable access in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this code with a class definition:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :state

  @state = 4

  def check_state
    puts "state is #{@state}"
  end
end

obj = Test.new
obj.check_state
```

There is no output of instance variable value.

But if I call obj.state = 4 before obj.check_state, I will get
"state is 4".

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you're defining an instance variable on the Test *class*, rather than on instances of Test. That is, you could access it with a class method:

```
class Test
  @state = 4
  def self.state
    @state
  end
end

# Test.state
#  => 4
```

But that's not what you want here; you don't want that value to be present on your class, you want it to be present for each instance of your class. To initialize instance variables on instances of classes, you should provide a constructor:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :state

  def initialize
    @state = 4
  end

  def check_state
    puts "state is #{@state}"
  end
end

# Test.new.state
#  => 4
```

Comment: so the only difference between instance variable and class instance variable, is one is inside instance method, the other the outside instance method?

Comment: Kinda. Classes are instances themselves, and as such, can have instance variables. There are also class variables (ie, `@@state`), but they behave differently WRT inheritance.

Comment: There is no difference between instance variables and class instance variables, because there is no such thing as a class instance variable. Classes are objects just like any other object, thus, they can have instance variables just like any other object. There's nothing special or different about that.

Answer (score -1):

self variable(current object) inside class definition is class object itself not the receiver object.
self is receiver(obj),  only inside  method definition.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2sgQ38UDVY
at 48 minute...

```
    class Test 
      attr_accessor :state  
      puts self.inspect
      @state = 4
      def check_state    
        puts "state is #{@state}"    
        puts self.inspect   
      end
   end
  obj = Test.new
  obj.state=4
  obj.check_state
```